# TYPO3 9 routing - .html

Tags: typo3-9.x, symfony-routing

Is there a possibility to configure routing in TYPO3 v9 to have `.html` applied to every URL? In `ext:realurl` and TYPO3 v8 (and previous versions) configuration `defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev` could have been used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, TYPO3 v9 supports "page decorators" that need to be configured individually in corresponding site configuration (either in `config/sites/` or `typo3conf/sites/`).

```
routeEnhancers:
   PageTypeSuffix:
      type: PageType
      default: '.html'
      index: 'index'
      map:
         '.json': 10
```

The example above is mapping (default) `&type=0` to `.html` suffix and `&type=10` to `.json` suffix - similar to RealURL's `fileName` property.

#### References

- TYPO3 v9 routing docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#page-type-decorator
- Previous RealURL docs: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#defaulttohtmlsuffixonprev